# Finding partial name of property in object with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var user = {
 "user_number12": "1234",
 "user_number14": "1235",
 "email": "joe@yahoo.com"
}
```

I want to find all users by searching the property string for "user_number" with lodash.

```
_.has(_.includes(user, "user_number"))
```

doesn't work. I just want to know how to chain together `_.ha`s and `_.includes`

Comment: `_.has` and `_.includes` just return `true` or `false`, it doesn't return the properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `_.pickBy`. It returns an object containing all the properties that a predicate returns a truthy value for. You can use `_.includes()` in the predicate.

```js
var user = {
 "user_number12": "1234",
 "user_number14": "1235",
 "email": "joe@yahoo.com"
}
var newUser = _.pickBy(user, (value, key) => _.includes(key, "user_number"))
console.log(newUser);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```